# How to count numbers in an aggregation in sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I want to aggregate groups of points that share the same location and then count the number of each class that belongs to the point.

My aggregation query is as follows:

```
create table mytable2 as
select count(*) as rows, location, string_agg(distinct class, ', ' order by class)
from mytable
group by location
```

The outcome of this gives me a row of for example

```
 (16, 'Wakanda', 'warrior priest tank')
```

How do I aggregate it to show instead

```
(16, 'Wakanda', '10 warrior 5 priest 1 tank')
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results *as text tables* would really help.  Where does the 10 come from?  Are you talking about multiple rows or multiple columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example data:

```
create table mytable(location text, class text);
insert into mytable values
('Wakanda', 'warrior'),
('Wakanda', 'warrior'),
('Wakanda', 'priest'),
('Wakanda', 'tank'),
('Wakanda', 'tank'),
('Wakanda', 'warrior');
```

Use [grouping sets.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-GROUPING-SETS) You can easily get a nice tabular output:

```
select location, class, count(*)
from mytable
group by grouping sets ((location), (location, class));

 location |  class  | count 
----------+---------+-------
 Wakanda  | priest  |     1
 Wakanda  | tank    |     2
 Wakanda  | warrior |     3
 Wakanda  |         |     6
(4 rows)
```

or a single row for a location, e.g.:

```
select
    max(count) as units,
    location, 
    string_agg(class || ': ' || count, ', ') as counts
from (
    select location, class, count(*)
    from mytable
    group by grouping sets ((location), (location, class))
    ) s
group by location;

 units | location |             counts             
-------+----------+--------------------------------
     6 | Wakanda  | priest: 1, tank: 2, warrior: 3
(1 row)
```

Comment: The format is just what I wanted, however I think your grouping sets is messing with my original count column in my select (I need total count in a separate column). It is showing something like: units 3 | location wakanda | counts tank4 warrior10

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want two levels of aggregation:

```
select lc.location,
       string_agg(class || '(' || cnt || ')', ', ' order by cnt desc)
from (select location, class, count(*) as cnt
      from mytable
      group by location, class
     ) lc
group by lc.location;
```

I put the string in what I consider a more reasonable format.  It would look like:  'warrior (10), priest (5), tank (1)'.  It is ordered by the frequency.  You can (of course) adjust the syntax to get some other format if you like.

Comment: Again format is just right but the count is not matching up with my first select (for example, it's counting more warriors than the count(*) in the select)